# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC

Tags: java, slf4j

How to fix `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.MDC`? I have in `pom.xml` flyway plugin where `slf4j` is excluded in favor of newer one.

```
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-spring4-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcloverslf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please share you `pom.xml` file.

Comment: If I could bet rep, I'd bet that the problem is mismatched SLF4J jars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.6:compile
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
```

These versions need to match. They don't match. At the very least, the minor versions (X in 1.X) need to match up. Also, get rid of slf4j-simple if you're using logback. Only one slf4j backend should be on the classpath.